# Apache HTTP Basic Auth - 401 error after supplying username and password

Tags: django, apache, apache2, httpd.conf, bitnami

I am attempting to configure my amazon server with Apache Http to prompt the user for username/password upon hitting the domain via browser.

Here is a snippet from my app.conf file (included in the httpd.conf)

```
Alias / "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "No Trespassing"
  AuthUserFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/users"
  Require valid-user

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Satisfy all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
  Require all granted
</IfVersion>
  ErrorDocument 403 "Authentication error"
</Directory>
```

After logging in I am redirected to a 401 "Authorization error" page. Any reason here? I am thinking perhaps my other .conf file causes some conflict.

In httpd.conf I have the following:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/bitnami/apps/django/scripts/djangoApp.wsgi
<Directory '/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/djangoApp'>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Satisfy all
</Directory>
```

Could the first line of each of those snippets be causing a conflict here, preventing me from logging in? I am not sure, but they both look to be creating a similar alias.

If there are any more details I should provide, please let me know.

Here is the error in the logs:

```
[Wed Jan 09 03:49:49 2013] [error] [client X.X.X.X] client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocsindex.html
[Wed Jan 09 03:49:49 2013] [error] [client X.X.X.X] client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocsfavicon.ico
[Wed Jan 09 03:50:28 2013] [error] [client X.X.X.X] client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocsindex.html
[Wed Jan 09 03:50:28 2013] [error] [client X.X.X.X] client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocsfavicon.ico
[Wed Jan 09 03:50:28 2013] [error] [client X.X.X.X] client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocsfavicon.ico
```

Comment: please `ls -l /opt/bitnami/apache2/users`; the default user for the apache daemon is www-data in ubuntu. Is www-data able to read the password file?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 49 Jan  9 02:50 users

Comment: should group have r+w permissions?

Comment: Since file is owned by root and www-data is not in the root group, the group permissions have no effect. To be sure, `su - www-data -c "cat /opt/bitnami/apache2/users"` - no error, you are ok.

Comment: It is asking for a password, not sure which password it is asking for...I tried a bunch of them

Comment: Could possibly the "users" file be blank?

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file in the same dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is one of 2 things:

#### potential solution #1

Simply that the user that Apache is running as doesn't have access to the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs` directory.

See this page for more details on dealing with the "client denied by server configuration errors": http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration

Check to see what user/groups are set on the `/opt/bitnami` directory tree. Make sure that they're friendly to the Apache user.

#### potential solution #2

Also if you look at your error messages the path is missing a '/' after htdocs. See the paths:

```
/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocsindex.html
/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocsfavicon.ico
```

I think you need to add a trailing slash, '/', to your `Alias` line like so:

```
Alias / "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/"
```

Comment: Solution #2 seemed to help, auth worked, but then redirected me to a different page after login completed. I think I will give you credit for this since it did help me get a little closer to the final solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would try some changes.

First your first `Alias / "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"` would easily be replaced by a `DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs` instruction.

Then you have several Aliases in place, both for "/". Instead of url-filesystem mapping instructions like Alias and AliasMap I would simple use a Location instruction for the security settings.

```
<Location />
  (... Auth basic stuff)
<Location>
```

By using **Location** you work on the url and not on the filesystem mapping.

Comment: the problem here is that I would like all urls to be inaccessible until the user has been authenticated...does the Location instruction handle this with something like Location * ?

Comment: Yes' Location / means all locations under /. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/fr/mod/core.html#location, Location is handled after Directory and Files, and locations apply as path prefix. And / is a path prefix of all paths.

Comment: after using Location authentication seemed to work a little better, but I was still taken to an error page (an internal server error page).